# Tastypie huge filter parameter length

Tags: django, nginx, python-requests, tastypie, gunicorn

I've written an API to query a database for stock information. Each client of my program will have about 2000 or so objects, each with an ID. The ID is then used to filter against the API to grab additional information from the database by ID. So, each client is submitting a request with a filter that looks like this:

```
id__in=ID12341234,ID123490987,ID12345678,ID098861234...
```

This works fine with a smallish number of IDs. However, when a client has several thousand of these, the request length is over 40,000 bytes as each id is about 15 characters. Putting these as params in a GET request gets me a 414 Error from both Nginx & Gunicorn (I'm running NGINX as reverse proxy for Gunicorn). I've already increased the header buffer size and the max request line length of NGINX & Gunicorn respectively, but both of those settings have sensible maximum values which even at their maximum, my requests are way over the limit. So, I'm wondering what can be done to get this type of request accomplished. Basically, I need to a query to a database and filter by a very large number of parameters. I'm using the **requests** library to query the Tastypie API. I've tried several combinations of using GET with "params" argument, or GET with "data" argument, or POST with "params" vs "data" and nothing seems to work. Using GET with params results in a 400 Error, using GET with data, results in:

```
ChunkedEncodingError: ('Connection broken: IncompleteRead(1781 bytes read)', IncompleteRead(1781 bytes read))
```

Using POST with params results in 400 Error, using POST with data results in:

```
The format indicated 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' had no available deserialization method. Please check your ``formats`` and ``content_types`` on your Serializer.
```

I appreciate any insight anyone has about getting this done besides splitting the parameters into multiple, separate requests.

Thanks!

Comment: You want to filter out 2000 ids? You could post it, show us your code.